# How to use Groovy and Spock to test Apach Flink Job?

Tags: groovy, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have a `Flink` job that reads data from `Kafka` into a table which is emitted into a `DataStream` on which I apply a filter function and then convert the data stream back to a table which writes data back to `Kafka`.

I want to test the functionality of the filter function. I am writing unit tests in `Groovy` using `Spock` (framework). In my unit test I am calling the `Flink` job with the Table SQL string with details about the `Kafka` topic, however, I am confused on how to load the right `StreamExecution` and `TableEnvironment` because when I create a new object of my `Flink` class, those values are `null` and I don't have getters/setters to set everything up because that would make the code really messy.

The following is my logic. My question is can I write `Apache Flink` APIs as seamlessly in `Groovy` or there are many layers/pitfalls and how can I better approach these tests:

```
class DataStreamTests extends Specification {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationConfiguration configuration;
    FlinkStreaming streaming = new FlinkStreaming();
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings
            .newInstance()
            .inStreamingMode()
            .build();
    final StreamTableEnvironment tableEnvironment = TableEnvironment.create(settings);
    
    def resourcePath = "cars/porche.txt"
    StreamSpec streamSpec = ConfigurationParser.createStreamSpec(getClass().getResource(resourcePath).text)
    
    def "create a new input stream from input table sql"() {
        given:
        DataStream<String> streamRecords = env.readTextFile("/streaming_signals/pedals.txt")
        streaming.setConfiguration(configuration)
        streaming.setTableEnvironment(tableEnvironment);
    
        when:
        String tableSpec = streaming.createTableSpec(streamSpec);
        DataStream<Row> rawStream = streaming.getFilteredStream(streamSpec, tableSpec)
        DataStream<String> comapareStreams = rawStream.map(new MapFunction<Row, String>() {
            @Override
            public String map(Row record) {
                // Logic to compare stream received with test stream
            }
        });
    
        then:
        // Comparison Logic

    }
}
```

```sh
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Could not find any factories that implement 'org.apache.flink.table.delegation.ExecutorFactory' in the classpath.
at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.discoverFactory(FactoryUtil.java:385)
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.create(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:295)
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.create(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:266)
at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.create(TableEnvironment.java:95)
at com.streaming.DataStreamTests.$spock_initializeFields(DataStreamTests.groovy:38
```